# Setting up ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a simple app that contains 2 fragments. One the left that contains a ListView and one on the right that contains a bunch of controls I will utilize:
[image]

I need to setup a list view in the fragment on the left but I cannot seem to get it right. I have setup up a ListView in the main activity but have never done it in a list view. The only restriction I have is that my values should come from SharedPrefrences and make use of a ArrayList and a ArrayAdapter. I have the following needs to happen:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String WORDS = "words";

private SharedPreferences conundrumWords;

private ArrayList<String> words;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    conundrumWords = getSharedPreferences(WORDS,MODE_PRIVATE);
    words = new ArrayList<>(conundrumWords.getAll().keySet());
    Collections.sort(words, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,words);
    getListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

This in my main activity but this will not work. What part of the section above should take place in the main activity and what part in the fragment's code?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? There is pretty much no difference in using a `ListView` in an `Activity` or a `Fragment`.

Comment: In the fragment's onCreateView, the adapter code and getListView code does not work

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?